# AJAX request doesnt get result for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
                var id = -1;

                function addMSG(dataz) {
                    console.log(dataz);
                }

                function waitForMsg() {
                    console.log("start waitmsg");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "chatxml2.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        timeout: 1000,
                        data: {id: id, chat: '.filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id").'},
                        datatype: "xml",


                        done: function(dataz) {
                            //addmsg(nera reikia);
                            addMSG(dataz);
                            console.log("success");
                        },

                        fail: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            //addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                            waitForMsg(); 
                            console.log("fail");
                        }
                    });
                }

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log(id);
                    waitForMsg(); 
                });
```

For some reason this doesn't get any result I'm not sure ifim using "data:" right.
I tried searching for a while but seems like I cant solve that, I'm quite bad at js.

PHP script is working 100% correcly, tried it with html script post.

Comment: `$.ajax` doesn't read `done:` and `fail:` properties on the options object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: using a `fixit: function () {alert("hi");}` also won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. `done` and `fail` should be `success` and `error` respectively.

So it should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "chatxml2.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 1000,
    data: {id: id, chat: '.filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id").'},
    datatype: "xml",
    success: function(dataz) {
        //addmsg(nera reikia);
        addMSG(dataz);
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

If you want to use Deferred syntax then it would be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "chatxml2.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 1000,
    data: {id: id, chat: '.filter_input(INPUT_GET,"id").'},
    datatype: "xml"
}).done(function() {
    addMSG(dataz);
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("fail");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace done by sucess and fail by error

read about Deferred object for aviable done and fail.